# C++ dynamically show or hide FLTK widgets?

Tags: c++, macros, fltk

I'm new to C++ and never used macros before but I beleive they may allow me to solve the following problem although I would welcome alternative solutions.

I have written the following macro:

```
#define COMMAND(NUMBER){ button_ ## NUMBER ## ->hide(); }
```

and I want to call it like this

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
    COMMAND(i)
}
```

in the hope that when the program executes it would do the equivalent of:

```
button_1->hide();
button_2->hide();
button_3->hide();
button_4->hide();
       .
       .
button_10->hide();
```

The idea is that I want to make a FLTK GUI display/hide widgets dynamically depending on a configuration file being read in when the form is loaded.

Unfortunately it appears that the macro above doesn't work and instead what it does is

```
button_i->hide();
```

which causes a compile error because button_i doesn't exist!

So my questions are:
A) Is it possible to do this in C++?
B) Is a macro able to accomplish this?
C) If not what can?
D) If macros can do this then how do I amend the above code to actually get it to work!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is a way to make a macro trick work, but there are better options.

You can, for example, store your buttons in an array.

Assuming your buttons have a type called `struct button`, declare your buttons like this:

```
struct button *buttons[42];
```

You need to initialize all of them as you would have for your individual button_X variables.

```
button[i] = <whatever you do to create button number i>;
```

Then you can simply do:

```
for (int i=0; i<42; i++) {
  button[i]->hide();
}
```

Or toggle any individual button with just its number. You'll probably find that better than any macro trick in the long run.

(Warning: arrays are `0`-based, so your first button is `button[0]`)

Comment: Damn, you beat me by 19 seconds ;)

Comment: You're right, storing in an array is a much better solution. I found [a good fltk specific solution here](http://www.mail-archive.com/fltk@easysw.com/msg04350.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the `button_2` etc. variables, I would recommend using an array instead. That way you could use a look like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
  button[i]->hide();
}
```

Of course, this is trivial to place in a macro.

In general, you can't accomplish what you want with a plain loop in C. However, if you *really* want to go that route, look at the boost preprocessor package.

Answer (score -1):

Do not try to manage the buttons yourself, FLTK does not like that.  You will have an awesome array of buttons that you cannot see.  I am not sure how to do it the way you want but I would do it this way:

```
Fl_Button * o = (Fl_Button *)myWindow->child(i);
o->hide();
```

and let the buttons be children of the FLTK window.